# UI is blocked when trying to update

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I want to start learning async and I have started a small application to do that. I read from a file and I am updating my UI, but the UI is blocking when I try to update. I have the following command and method:

```
LoadTextFileCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await LoadTextFileExecute());
        
    private async Task LoadTextFileExecute()
    {
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != true)
            return;

        var result = await ReadFileAsync(openFileDialog.FileName);

        Text = Encoding.Default.GetString(result);

        Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(result));
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> ReadFileAsync(string path)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            var result = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            
            await fileStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

            return result;
        }
    }

    <TextBox
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="10,10,10,10"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Debug.WriteLine it is writing faster than the UI is updated.
When I try to update Text (which is bound to a textbox), the UI is blocked for a few seconds.
I am not sure what I need to change so I can do other tasks on my application while the text is read and UI is updated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `await fileStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);` You are not doing this safely. You are assuming all of the file contents will be read in a single call. This is not correct. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.readasync?view=net-5.0 `The result value can be less than the number of bytes requested`

Comment: This code won't block. The entire `ReadFileAsync` could be replaced with [File.ReadAllBytesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytesasync?view=net-5.0) though or better yet, if you want to read text, with `File.ReadAllTextAsync`. If the stored file isn't English or UTF8, you can specify the encoding you want.

Comment: As for `Debug.WriteLine it is writing faster than the UI is updated.` yes, because data binding hasn't been activated yet at that point. If something freezes, it's code outside this method. Post your actual form, data binding, MVVM

Comment: Maybe your Text is so big that rendering it in UI takes those 2 seconds

Comment: @evk The thing is that the application is blocked (I cannot do anything related to the application when it is blocked, I cannot move or click any button). I expect to be able do move or do else while I read and update the file

Comment: I mean not reading but specifically rendering text in UI. That should of course happen on UI thread and will block. If text is really huge - it will take some time to render, no matter what

Comment: Note, that you don't really do asynchronous I/O. Read this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58723825/580053